# EJS Statements in Plain HTML File and in TypeScript

Tags: express, angular, gulp

I'm trying to wrap my head around a [seed project for Angular 2](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed) which has a lot of moving parts, and I came across something that I don't understand... In the index.html there are what appear to be ejs statements:

```
<!-- src/client/index.html -->
<title><%= APP_TITLE %></title>
```

Although I understand **WHAT** it's doing (allowing the title to be defined in a config file), I don't understand **HOW** it's doing it. While I do see [express](http://expressjs.com/), I don't see [ejs](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) as a dependency in the `package.json`

To make it more confusing, there are similar ejs-like statements in some typescript files that look like this:

```
// src/client/app/system-config.ts
System.config(JSON.parse('<%= SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV %>'));

// src/client/app/app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes), AboutModule, HomeModule, SharedModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'    // <------- this!?!?
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

So, this same interpolation is working outside of a template!? How does this work? What tool or package is facilitating this replacement? I can't figure it out. I believe [this is the code](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/blob/master/tools/utils/seed/server.ts) for running the server:

```
/**
 * Starts a new `express` server, serving the built files from `dist/prod`.
 */

export function serveProd() {
  let root = resolve(process.cwd(), Config.PROD_DEST);
  let server = express();

  server.use(Config.APP_BASE, express.static(root));

  server.use(fallback('index.html', { root }));

  server.listen(Config.PORT, () =>
    openResource('http://localhost:' + Config.PORT + Config.APP_BASE)
  );
};
```

I know Express comes with EJS support out-of-the-box, however, it requires the file to have an `.ejs` extension. I know there is a way to force it to parse regular `.html` files, but that code does not seem exist in the angular seed project.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what it was just a few minutes after posting my question. Drumroll please...
It's `gulp-template`, not EJS. It's simply underscore templating that gulp is replacing with config values at build time. So, mystery solved.

Comment: This explains the `index.html` file, but I'm still not sure how this translates to the source code (the `.ts` files)